# Writing to partition table vs staging and switch in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am developing a SSIS package and migrating billions of records into the destination table. I have currently created 5 staging tables and used a split function to segregate the records by year for each staging table.

I am planning to partition the main destination table and then switch the 5 staging records to it. I would like to  know if it is better for the SSIS to write directly to the partition or write to a staging tables and then perform a switch to the partition table.

Could somebody tell me which is the desired approach ?

Conditional split in SSIS

[image]

Comment: I am unsure of your question honestly. From a design standpoint are you wanting to take the 5 tables and place them into one destination table?

Comment: Hi Kyle, from design stand point what i am currently planning to do is switch the data from staging table to partition table. So it will be like stage1 data moved to partion1 of destination, stage2 data to partition2 etc.

Comment: I am comparing it against dumping the data into destination partioned table directly from source via SSIS without using staging table

Comment: Tom, if your not planning on doing any additional logic on the data when moving them to staging tables then I would just dump the data into destination partitioned table directly and save yourself work.

Comment: The reason why I am using staging tables is because the data is split based on year field. I am not sure how will SSIS know where to dump the right data in the right partition

Comment: Can you provide a visual of the table you want inserted into? My first thought is a conditional split but that may not work here.

Comment: I have updated the post with the conditional split that i am using. Its moving data to the staging table as I mentioned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157491/discussion-between-kyle-pearson-and-tom).

Comment: without a trial/error attempt, it's hard to say. i think you will find what performs best by testing both routes, if indeed you can get the partition approach to work as you intend it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion back and forth (see discussion) it seems the in this case have staging tables is not the best method. You have a partition already created to handle a single table and splitting that into many staging tables is more work that is not needed.